# covering map of space onto connected space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\rho: E \to B$ be a covering map with $B$ connected. Show if $\rho^{-1}(\{b_0\})$ has $k$ elements for some $b_0 \in B$ then $\rho^{-1}(\{b\})$ has $k$ elements for all $b \in B$.

Attempt: Consider the set

$$K=\{b \in B : \text{$\rho^{-1}(\{b\})$ has $k$ elements}\}$$

Claim: $K \subset B$ is non-empty, closed and open (in $B$) and is thus all of $B$. For non-empty, we know $b_0 \in K$ thus $K$ is non-empty. However, I'm having a tough time showing $K$ is both open and closed in $B$. What does $\rho^{-1}(\{b\})$ even look like? I was sort of thinking for showing its open that if $x \in K$, then $x \in B$ and $\rho^{-1}(\{x\})$ has $k$ elements. Now are these $k$ elements disjoint open subsets of $E$ since $\rho$ is a covering map? Such that the restriction of any of them onto $\{x\}$ is a homeomorphism? or does this only hold for open subsets of $B$? How does one merely use the fact that the preimage has $k$ elements to conclude it's both open and closed??

Answer (score 2):

Let $b \in B$ arbitrary.
Then, since $\rho \colon E \to B$ is a covering map, there is an open set $U$ in $B$ containing $b$ and a family $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of disjoint open sets in $E$ such that:

- $\rho^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$;
- for each $i \in I$, $\rho \colon U_i \to U$ is a homeomorphism.

Notice that if $x \in U$, for each $i \in I$ one has that $|U_i \cap \rho^{-1}(\{x\})|=1$ (otherwise, $\rho \colon U_i \to U$ is not injective).
Thus, for $x \in U$, the equality
$$
\rho^{-1}(\{x\}) = \rho^{-1}(U) \cap \rho^{-1}(\{x\}) = \bigcup_{i \in I} \big( U_i \cap \rho^{-1}(\{x\}) \big)
$$
implies that
$$
|\rho^{-1}(\{x\})| = \sum_{i \in I} |U_i \cap \rho^{-1}(\{x\})| = \sum_{i \in I} 1 = |I|.
$$
In particular, $|\rho^{-1}(\{b\})|=|I|$ (since $b \in U$). So:
$$
\forall x \in U \quad |\rho^{-1}(\{x\})| = |\rho^{-1}(\{b\})|. \tag1
$$
Finally, observe that if we assume from the beginning that $b \in K$, then $(1)$ implies that $U \subseteq K$, and so $K$ is open.

Similarly, if $b \notin K$, then $U \subseteq B \setminus K$, and so $B \setminus K$ is open.

Comment: How do you get in particular, the order of the fiber of $b$ is the size of $I$

Comment: @MyMathYourMath Just because $b \in U$.